# Move some free space to Macintosh HD (Startup Disk)

Tags: disk-utility, partition

On my mac hard disk, Macintosh HD (Startup Disk) is almost full, I need to increase the size of Macintosh merging some free space from my another partition. But I tried all possible ways, free space always merged to same partition, not to Macintosh HD.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions and answers. As you all suggested there is no way to do this using disk utility, Seems need to have some 3rd party software.

Only way to achieve something similar to above using Disk Utility is:

According to image attached above, I had to move all data from "Software" partition to somewhere else and delete "Software" partition and merge free space to "Macintosh HD"

Answer (score 2):

This requires the three partitions between the selected one and the intended one to be moved. Disk Utility can't do this without destructively destroying and recreating the partitions in the intended location, removing all data from the partitions. You will need third-party software such as iPartition. For more information, see [Partitioning Software](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101928/partitioning-software/).

Comment: To George's point, try a partitioning software such as Stellar, or iPartition. I'm partial to the former, and it does what you're wanting to do.