# Can I remove one partition on an external drive, while keeping the other intact?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, external-disk

I have an external USB drive, which I've partitioned into separate FAT32 ("MOVIES") and OSX ("TIME_MACHINE") partitions:

[image]

I now wish to remove the FAT32 partition and just use the OSX partition.

Aside from reformating the disk with a single OSX partition, is it possible to:

- remove/erase the FAT32 partition, then
- expand the OSX partition to take up the entire drive

without losing the contents of the OSX partition?

Comment: See [Partitioning Software](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101928/partitioning-software)

Comment: The whole drive died in the end, which was one way to resolve the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk Utility can't do it, but iPartition can - http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php

Tested on both GUID & MBR formatted drives.

Comment: Is there any similar and free solution? I probably only need to resize once

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101928/partitioning-software/268637#268637 for a more comprehensive answer